# How to display array value separately with selected column?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I want to display array 1 by 1.. 1st array value display thnn 2nd array value

I want to display array data using loop and display data separatelylike 1st array data display then 2nd array data will display. and i want to display data only entrydate n description. with loop count

> $svs= $user_posts->getvalue('service', $dsplylimit );
>
> var_dump($svs);

**My array is like this**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
     array (size=46)
       0 => string '74' (length=2)
      'id' => string '74' (length=2)
       1 => string '0' (length=1)
      'author' => string '0' (length=1)
       2 => string '2016-02-08 07:32:08' (length=19)
      'entrydate' => string '2016-02-08 07:32:08' (length=19)
       3 => string '2016-02-08 01:32:08' (length=19)
      'date_gmt' => string '2016-02-08 01:32:08' (length=19)
       4 => string 'nice email' (length=10)
      'description' => string 'nice email' (length=10)
  1 => 
     array (size=46)
       0 => string '75' (length=2)
       'id' => string '75' (length=2)
       1 => string '0' (length=1)
       'author' => string '0' (length=1)
       2 => string '2016-02-08 11:15:40' (length=19)
       'entrydate' => string '2016-02-08 11:15:40' (length=19)
       3 => string '2016-02-08 05:15:40' (length=19)
       'date_gmt' => string '2016-02-08 05:15:40' (length=19)
       4 => string 'hiiiiiii' (length=8)
       'description' => string 'hiiiiiii' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very clear what you want to do, but you can probably display the data with a `foreach` loop. Just loop through each array, and then print out the values from each iteration that you want.

For example for the following array

```
$data = [
    ['entrydate' => '2016-01-01', 'description' => 'Some description here'],
    ['entrydate' => '2016-01-02', 'description' => 'Another description here']
];
```

You could print out the data like so:

```
$html = '';

foreach ($data as $array) {
    $html .= '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars($array['entrydate']) . '</h1>';
    $html .= '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($array['description']) . '</p>';
}

echo $html;
```

For the following output:

> **2016-01-01**
>
> Some description here
>
> **2016-01-02**
>
> Another description here

There's a chance I'm not understanding your requirements, if so just let me know, but I'm not 100% sure what it is you're after.

Comment: i wnt to display entrydate in <h1> tag ex.. <h1>entrydate</h1> already i give u my array data how to display entrydate in <h1> tag?? @Virtual Pigeon

Comment: @KevinPPatel Updated my answer, feel free to see if that is what you need.